# Is there a faster way to parse hashtags than using Regular Expressions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, hashtag

I am curious, is there a faster/better way to parse hashtags in a string, other than using Regular Expressions (mainly in Ruby)?

**Edit**
For example I want to parse the string `This is a #hashtag, and this is #another one!` and get the words `#hashtag` and `#another`. I am using `#\S+` for my regex.

Comment: What regex are you currently using? Also, I doubt there is any faster way. Regex operations are optimized by MRI as they use a lot of C code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That seems absolutely legit to me, then. Can't think of an easier variant.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Do you want to put some values into the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show any code (which you should have) so we're guessing how you are using your regex.

`#\S+` is as good of a pattern as you'll need, but `scan` is probably the best way to retrieve all occurrences in the string.

```
'This is a #hashtag, and this is #another one!'.scan(/#\S+/)
=> ["#hashtag,", "#another"]
```

---

> Its should be /\B#\w+/, if you don't want to parse commas

Yes, I agree. [`/\B#\w+/`](https://www.regex101.com/r/mY0aH8/1) makes more sense.

Comment: That regex is incorrect. If I were to have the string: http://google.com#tag it pulls out the #tag where this isn't actually a hash tag. The regex should be: \B#\S+

Comment: What does `\B` do? @MikeSilvis

Comment: Its should be /\B#\w+/, if you don't want to parse commas

Answer (score 4):

#### Maybe

Hmm, ideas....

- You could try `s.split('#')`, and then perhaps apply a regex only to actual hashtags
  `s.split('#').drop(1).map { |x| x[/\w+/] }` --- it may or may not be any faster but it clearly is uglier
- You could write a C extension that extracts hashtags
- You could profile your program and see if it really needs any optimization for this case.